# MongoDB Match Text Search in Nested Array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested, aggregation

I have the following collection in MongoDB Atlas and I want to extract only the relevant object(s) from the supplier_items_catalogue array(s) using $text $search in the aggregation pipeline:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "63f4551a871a50c6a39dcaa3"
    },
    "supplier_name": "Willy's Wines",
    "supplier_id": "WLW-1",
    "supplier_email": [
      {
        "supplier_email_name": "Admin",
        "supplier_email_address": "admin@blah.com",
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "63f4551a871a50c6a39dcaa4"
        }
      },
    ],
    "supplier_payment_terms": "30 Days",
    "supplier_delivery_terms": "Next Day",
    "supplier_items_catalogue": [
      {
        "supplier_item_sku_id": "WN001",
        "supplier_item_sku_description": "Blue Mountains Sauvignon Blanc",
        "supplier_item_uom": "BO750",
        "supplier_item_uom_description": "750ml bottle",
        "supplier_item_price": 42,
        "supplier_item_quantity_per_uom": 1,
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "63f4551a871a50c6a39dcaa8"
        }
      },
      {
        "supplier_item_sku_id": "WN002",
        "supplier_item_sku_description": "Blue Mountains Pinot Noir",
        "supplier_item_uom": "BO750",
        "supplier_item_uom_description": "750ml bottle",
        "supplier_item_price": 37,
        "supplier_item_quantity_per_uom": 1,
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "63f4551a871a50c6a39dcaa9"
        }
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "63f4551a871a50c6a39dcaa3"
    },
    "supplier_name": "Hills Liqour Store",
    "supplier_id": "HLL-1",
    "supplier_email": [
      {
        "supplier_email_name": "Admin",
        "supplier_email_address": "admin@blah.com",
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "63f4551a871a50c6a39dcaa5"
        }
      },
    ],
    "supplier_payment_terms": "30 Days",
    "supplier_delivery_terms": "Next Day",
    "supplier_items_catalogue": [
      {
        "supplier_item_sku_id": "HL001",
        "supplier_item_sku_description": "Table Mountain Sauvignon Blanc",
        "supplier_item_uom": "BO750",
        "supplier_item_uom_description": "750ml bottle",
        "supplier_item_price": 43,
        "supplier_item_quantity_per_uom": 1,
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "63f4551a871a50c6a39dcab0"
        }
      },
      {
        "supplier_item_sku_id": "HL002",
        "supplier_item_sku_description": "Table Mountain Pinot Noir",
        "supplier_item_uom": "BO750",
        "supplier_item_uom_description": "750ml bottle",
        "supplier_item_price": 36,
        "supplier_item_quantity_per_uom": 1,
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "63f4551a871a50c6a39dcab1"
        }
      },
      {
        "supplier_item_sku_id": "HL003",
        "supplier_item_sku_description": "Uluru Pinot Grigio",
        "supplier_item_uom": "BO750",
        "supplier_item_uom_description": "750ml bottle",
        "supplier_item_price": 34,
        "supplier_item_quantity_per_uom": 1,
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "63f4551a871a50c6a39dcab2"
        }
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

**Desired result:**

If the search text is 'Pinot', I would like the returned data to be as follows:

```
[
  {
    "supplier_name": "Willy's Wines",
    "supplier_id": "WLW-1",
    "supplier_payment_terms": "30 Days",
    "supplier_item_sku_id": "WN002",
    "supplier_item_sku_description": "Blue Mountains Pinot Noir",
    "supplier_item_uom_description": "750ml bottle",
    "supplier_item_price": 37,
  },
  {
    "supplier_name": "Hills Liqour Store",
    "supplier_id": "HLL-1",
    "supplier_payment_terms": "30 Days",
    "supplier_item_sku_id": "HL002",
    "supplier_item_sku_description": "Table Mountain Pinot Noir",
    "supplier_item_uom_description": "750ml bottle",
    "supplier_item_price": 36,
  },
  {
    "supplier_name": "Hills Liqour Store",
    "supplier_id": "HLL-1",
    "supplier_payment_terms": "30 Days",
    "supplier_item_sku_id": "HL003",
    "supplier_item_sku_description": "Uluru Pinot Grigio",
    "supplier_item_uom_description": "750ml bottle",
    "supplier_item_price": 34,
  },
```

So far, I have managed to get the desired output format by using the following query but this is only working using an exact match (e.g. the search text is 'Uluru Pinot Grigio'):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "supplier_items_catalogue.supplier_item_sku_description": "Uluru Pinot Grigio"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$supplier_items_catalogue"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "supplier_items_catalogue.supplier_item_sku_description": "Uluru Pinot Grigio"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      supplier_name: "$supplier_name",
      supplier_id: "$supplier_id",
      payment_terms: "$supplier_payment_terms",
      sku_id: "$supplier_items_catalogue.supplier_item_sku_id",
      sku_description: "$supplier_items_catalogue.supplier_item_sku_description",
      uom_description: "$supplier_item_uom_description",
      item_price: "$supplier_item_price"
    }
  }
])
```

How can I include $match $text $search in the aggregation pipeline to achieve the desired result (I have added the text index to the supplier_items_catalogue.supplier_item_sku_description field)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the text index is not intended to be used in array entries. The best you can do is move the `$text` search to the first stage of aggregation. Then, perform a substring search using `$indexOfCP` after `$unwind` like

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $text: {
        $search: "Pinot"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$supplier_items_catalogue"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          -1,
          {
            "$indexOfCP": [
              "$supplier_items_catalogue.supplier_item_sku_description",
              "Pinot"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      supplier_name: "$supplier_name",
      supplier_id: "$supplier_id",
      payment_terms: "$supplier_payment_terms",
      sku_id: "$supplier_items_catalogue.supplier_item_sku_id",
      sku_description: "$supplier_items_catalogue.supplier_item_sku_description",
      uom_description: "$supplier_item_uom_description",
      item_price: "$supplier_item_price"
    }
  }
])
```

[Simplified Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TPdgAGNSlg8)

Comment: Thanks very much Ray, this does exactly what I want! I added $toLower to $indexOfCP to match the case insensitivity of $text and that seems to ignore case in the search. Thanks for your help!